# Jmeter checkpoint for a specific transaction

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

Is there something wrong with this code? I am trying to identify a failed user in JMeter when running a test. The script is absolutely working fine in my local and with a limited number of users. How can I print the failing users in the log while using distributed testing? I am running 100 users per machine(5 slaves with the master)

My first transaction has 10 requests and in the request post processor i am using the below code to print in the log. But where exactly it will be shown in distributed load test and i am using Apdex report finally but it doesn't show up even there.

if(prev.getResponseCode()=='500')
{
log.info('Failed User: ' + '${__threadNum}-${Username}-${MachineIp}-${__machineName}');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will appear in `jmeter.log` file (or `jmeter-server.log` file, depending on the way how do you start the slave) **on the machine where it failed**

If you want  to see this in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) - you need to use [prev.setResponseMessage()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseMessage-java.lang.String-) function

Also don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts as it conflicts with [GString templates](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine) and only first occurrence will be cached and used on subsequent iterations

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Suggested code change:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils

if (prev.getResponseCode() == '500') {
    prev.setResponseMessage('Failed User: ' + ctx.getThreadNum() + '-' + vars.get('Username') + '-' + JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP() + '-' + JMeterUtils.getLocalHostName());
}
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri, In this case how to stop that user who enters this condition?

Comment: And the jmx should exists on all the slave machine or will it take from master? The reason is that i am thinking whether to update in master or all slave machine also

Comment: Hi George, if you will have 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. question are you going to ask them like this? There is "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" setting on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level where you can choose what happens when the error occurs. If you need to do this from Groovy - use the following line: `ctx.getThread().stop()`. More information on JMeter API shorthands: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Sorry Dimitri. I didn't mean that. But your views helped me. Thanks a lot